# Scale images to the [-1, 1] range

Tags: python

I have been looking in the Simple MNIST convnet code example provided by Keras https://keras.io/examples/vision/mnist_convnet/

Here they scale images to the [0,1] range

```
# Scale images to the [0, 1] range
x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255    
x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255
```

How can I scale it to [-1,1]?

Comment: I removed all those unnecessary tags since your question isn't about any of those topics.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something in the range [0, 1], then to transform this to [-1, 1] you simply need to multiply by 2 and subtract 1

```
x_train = (x_train.astype("float32") / 255) * 2 - 1    
x_test = (x_test.astype("float32") / 255) * 2 - 1
```

Alternatively, recognize that the endpoints of your original range (0-255) need to become -1 and 1, and the midpoint (255/2) needs to become 0. So subtract 255/2 from the original values, which will transform 0 to -127.5 and 255 to 127.5. Now, divide by 255/2 (i.e. 127.5)

```
x_train = (x_train.astype("float32") - 127.5) / 127.5
x_test = (x_test.astype("float32") - 127.5 ) / 127.5
```